# Python3 ParseError

Tags: python, parse-error

I was trying to do a simple task, a script that figures out which of numbers inputed were largest of smallest. Here is the code:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break
    try :
        num = int(num)
    except :
        print('Invalid input')
        continue

    if smallest is None :
        smallest = num
    elif: 
        smallest > num
        smallest = num

    if largest is None :
        largest = num
    elif :
    largest < num
    largest = num



print("Maximum", largest)
```

When I am trying to run the code, it tells me 'ParseError: bad input on line 15'

Could anybody help me?

Comment: The colon right after the elif is not how elif works...

Comment: `elif smallest > num :` i think is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for `elif` is the same as for normal `if` statements:

Instead of:

```
elif: 
    smallest > num
    smallest = num
```

Do:

```
elif smallest > num:
    smallest = num
```

Same for your other `elif` further down.